# Windows delete all vendors and node_modules

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10, git-bash

I have problems with deleting my node_modules and vendors folders.
I want to delete them all from computer, I found various of ways on internet and nothing helped actually.

This actually does delete them:

```
FOR /d /r . %d in (node_modules) DO @IF EXIST "%d" del -f "%d"
```

but it's asking me every time to type Y in cmd.

Is there any way of doing it with one command in cmd or git bash or powershell? I'm using windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Directory -Filter 'node_modules' |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
```

Just remove the `-WhatIf` parameter to do the actual deletion

---

If you want to target multiple folders recursively, you can do the following:

```
# Example 1: Using variable for readability
$folders = 'node_modules','vendors'
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Directory -Include $folders |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false -WhatIf

# Example 2: Not using variable
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Directory -Include 'node_modules','vendors' |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
```

I have heard that there could be a performance issue with using `-Recurse` and `-Include` together. I have never seen it myself, but keep that in mind if you have a large directory structure and see a performance degradation.